# MFC: How do you allow CMFCMenuBar to be hidden by user?

Tags: mfc, menubar

In MFC app you can right click toolbars and choose to hide them.   How do you have a `CMFCMenuBar` do the same thing.  If you go to "customize" you can't uncheck the checkbox for the menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the default `CMFCMenuBar m_wndMenuBar;` generated by the app wizard, the following toggles it between visible and hidden.

```
    m_wndMenuBar.ShowPane(!m_wndMenuBar.IsVisible(), 0, FALSE);
```

[`ShowPane`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbasepane-class?view=vs-2019#showpane) and [`IsVisible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbasepane-class?view=vs-2019#isvisible) are inherited from `CBasePane` via `CMFCMenuBar` `: CMFCToolBar` `: CMFCBaseToolBar` `: CPane` `: CBasePane`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way the user can do it with the built-in customize stuff or must I program is special option to do it?

Comment: @user3161924 I don't see the option in the stock UI, so I guess it would need to be coded 
separately.